# save Pdfstamper output to file object

Tags: java, file, pdf, itext

I am using iTextPdf for appending data to pdf but I want to save the modified file to a File object so that I can send that file to client server.

Code :

```
package doc;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.BaseFont;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfContentByte;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfStamper;

public class Doc_demo {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        try {
                        
            //Create PdfReader instance.
            PdfReader pdfReader = 
                new PdfReader("C:\\Users\\user1\\iTextPDFSamples\\user1\\SAMPLE_A071W471.pdf"); 
 
            //Create PdfStamper instance.
            PdfStamper pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader,
            new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\user1\\iTextPDFSamples\\user1\\ModifiedTestFile.pdf"));
 
            //Create BaseFont instance.
            BaseFont baseFont = BaseFont.createFont(
                    BaseFont.TIMES_ROMAN, 
                    BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
 
            //Get the number of pages in pdf.
            int pages = pdfReader.getNumberOfPages(); 
 
            //Iterate the pdf through pages.
            for(int i=1; i<=1; i++) { //i<=pages
            //Contain the pdf data.
            PdfContentByte pageContentByte = 
                    pdfStamper.getOverContent(i);
            //Set text font and size.
            pageContentByte.setFontAndSize(baseFont, 8);
 
            pageContentByte.beginText();
            pageContentByte.setTextMatrix(379, 615);
            pageContentByte.showText("SN01234567890");
            pageContentByte.endText();
            
            pageContentByte.beginText();
            pageContentByte.setTextMatrix(450, 615);
            pageContentByte.showText("European Union");
            pageContentByte.endText();
            }
 
            //Close the pdfStamper.
            pdfStamper.close(); 
 
            System.out.println("PDF modified successfully.");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Code works fine.

`pdfStamper.close();` this line will save the modified file to the given location but how to convert it to File object.

Comment: *"this line will save the modified file to the given location but how to convert it to File object."* - What do you mean by that question? If *the modified file is saved to the given location*, there is a file object at the given location, isn't there?

Comment: @mkl 

PdfStamper pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\user1\\iTextPDFSamples\\user1\\ModifiedTestFile.pdf"));

this line creates the modified file and when we close it that will write the content, there is no file object but FileOutstream instance is there

Answer (score 0):

Solved the issue :

*File **tempFile** = File.createTempFile("Tempfile",".pdf");*

created one tempfile and used this tempfile for pdfstamper's

```
PdfStamper pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, new FileOutputStream(tempFile));
```

This solved the issue.